# Is it possible to remain logged in to an external API in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In Laravel, I'm connecting to an external API like this from a custom Controller, and I get a JSON response.:

```
public function apicall($id) {

    $response = Http::withBasicAuth($this->username, $this->password)->get('api/url/' . $id);

     ...
```

Do I have to use the withBasicAuth every time I call the method(since it's mandatory on the server's side) , or can I create a custom BasicAuth middleware, log in once, and be able to do the API calls without the withBasicAuth everytime?

Comment: The idea of an API is that it is stateless, so won't save Auth information. What is the problem with doing your Auth everytime? You could potentially create your connection in your `__construct()` and then use it in your methods if you want to write less.

Comment: Of course the constructor, thanks. It helped.

Comment: I added the answer accordingly, glad it helped 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your constructor to set the connection and then use it in your methods:

```
    private $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = Http::withBasicAuth($this->username, $this->password);
    }

    public function apicall($id) {
        $response = $this->connection->get('api/url/' . $id);
        // ...
    }
```